# MySQL query w/ COUNT() and HAVING based on date comparison

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am trying to limit my count results to those that meet a specific criteria. I am currently using a WHERE clause and my output is as expected.

Here is my current query, and as you can see *ads_list* and *ads_cate* records will only be fetched if my WHERE *recdate* meets the 14 day mark:

```
$queryCats = "
SELECT ads_cate.cateName, COUNT(ads_list.Title)
FROM
ads_cate
JOIN ads_list ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)
GROUP BY ads_cate.cateName";
```

I would like all categories and ads retrieved, but counted ONLY when they meet my WHERE clause criteria. I have been using the HAVING with 0 luck like below. Maybe there is a better way?

```
$queryCats = "
SELECT ads_cate.cateName, ads_list.recdate, COUNT(ads_list.Title)
FROM
ads_cate
JOIN ads_list ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
GROUP BY ads_cate.cateName
HAVING to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)";
```

Comment: your first query already does that

Comment: Which table does `recdate` belong to?

Comment: The problem is my categories are not in my array to display in my results set. they are being filtered. I need all category names available in my array regardless of they meet that criteria or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `LEFT JOIN` and make the date test part of the join condition:

```
SELECT ac.cateName, COUNT(al.Title)
    FROM ads_cate ac
        LEFT JOIN ads_list al
            ON ac.id = al.category 
                AND to_days(now())<=(to_days(al.recdate)+14)
    GROUP BY ac.cateName
```

Comment: Joe, your sample was magic. I am guessing the al. Your presentation and approach is new to me such as the al. abbreviation on the LEFT JOIN.. I am guessing the al.Title (al portion) assigns the table that alias. Thanks for the interesting code.

Comment: You guessed right. The `al` alias is just a short hand way of referencing the `ads_list` table throughout the query. The alias is actually assigned when the table is referenced during the `LEFT JOIN ads_list al` portion of the code.

Comment: I see what you mean in that "ads_list al" fragment. Thanks for the helpful lesson.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
SELECT ads_cate.cateName, ads_list.recdate, COUNT(CASE WHEN to_days(now())<=to_days((recdate)+14) THEN ads_list.Title ELSE NULL END) AS Title
FROM
ads_cate
JOIN ads_list ON ads_cate.id = ads_list.category 
GROUP BY ads_cate.cateName
```

Comment: Try with `ELSE NULL`, not `ELSE 0` because `COUNT()` counts everything that is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your filtered counting in a subquery and then `LEFT JOIN` from the category table to the subquery.